# Salesforce to Salesforce Migration

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api, python, data-migration

We are doing Salesforce (old instance) to Salesforce (new instance) migration. We have Standard and custom objects in our old instance which are needed to be migrated to the new Salesforce instance. We are doing this in the following steps:-

1: Using salesforce describe rest api create tables in MySQL with similar mapping of salesforce object. Tables are created with referential integrity using "referenceTo" field of describe call. Example: services/data/v49.0/sobjects/User/describe/.

2: Get data from salesforce using query rest api and put into MySQL tables. Example: /services/data/v39.0/query/?q=.

3: In this part, we have some confusion like which api we should use so that we can push records to destination org.

We are using Python for this task.

Comment: [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/introduction_bulk_api_2.htm) and/or [Composite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_composite_resources.htm) and/or [individual objects' REST resource(s)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm). [simple-salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce) is an OSS Python lib that does some of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the composite sobject rows if you do not have a large payload of the order of 100K

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections.htm

A single request can take **200 records** so you will group the requests in this approach.

Another way is to use the **new graph composite api**.

This api is available as of today from winter 21

You can find details below

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_graph.htm

Work your payload so as to avoid the limits mentioned below.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_graph_limits.htm

This api can have 500 subrequests and hence is more powerful than simple composite api

Use a bulk API for large payloads of the order of millions.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/create_job.htm

You can get the processed IDs using the below API for bulk jobs

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/get_job_successful_results.htm

Comment: Bulk api batch results do not return newly created Id in destination org which we need to update in child records. Composite API return newly created Id with reference Id (which is old id, so that we can update child object in MySQL before sending them). Composite API have limit of 200 records in single request.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/get_job_successful_results.htm

Comment: @amit Results do return response once job is processed! You have to call the right api

Comment: Thanks, @Mohith Shrivastava,

Comment: We have a total of 100 objects (20 standard, 80 custom) which are needed to be migrated. Most of them are related to other objects with parent-child relationships.So if we use bulk api which are asynchronous in nature, so it can take some time to complete (which may vary).

Comment: So we have to wait before sending child records because require their parents are successfully created and we are sending newly created parent with them. If we have around 5 million records to insert in destination salesforce instance. It will take 25000 api call if we use Composite tree api which can process 200 records in a single request. The benefits of the composite tree in our case are: we get newly created Id in response with oldID, so we can update our MySQL database with newID and push child records.

Comment: Try using composite graph instead if you have too many related objects! It will be easier than composite if you have to go synchronous!